# Zoho creator integration with zoho books

Tags: zoho, zohobooks

So i recently started working with the Zoho platform so im quite new to it, ive been assigned the following task:

Build a Customer form on zoho creator with various different fields (name, company name, billing address and some extra custom fields.
Integrate the data from the form to the zoho books platform.

Basically, a user submit the form and on submission a new record on zoho books its created.

[image]

[image]

My issue, when the form is submitted theres no new customer on zoho books.

Can someone help me please

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
cpList = List();
firstName = input.Contact_Name.first_name;
lastName = input.Contact_Name.last_name;
contactName = firstName + " " + lastName;
contactMap = Map();
contactMap.put("contact_name",contactName);
contactMap.put("company_name",input.Company_Name);
contactMap.put("website",input.Website);
billingMap = Map();
billingMap.put("zip",input.Billing_Address.postal_Code);
billingMap.put("country",input.Billing_Address.country);
billingMap.put("address",input.Billing_Address.address_line_1);
billingMap.put("street2",input.Billing_Address.address_line_2);
billingMap.put("city",input.Billing_Address.district_city);
billingMap.put("state",input.Billing_Address.state_province);
contactP = Map();
contactP.put("first_name",firstName);
contactP.put("last_name",lastName);
contactP.put("designation",input.Designation);
contactP.put("department",input.Department);
contactP.put("contact_salutation","Mr/Mrs");
contactP.put("mobile",input.Mobile_Phone);
contactP.put("phone",input.Phone_Number);
contactP.put("email",input.Email);
contactP.put("is_primary_contact",true);
contactMap.put("billing_address",billingMap);
cpList.add(contactP);
contactMap.put("contact_persons",cpList);
params = Map();
params.put("JSONString",contactMap);
createContact = invokeurl
[
    url :"https://books.zoho.eu/api/v3/contacts?organization_id="
    type :POST
    parameters:params
    connection:"books"
];
```

This was the way i was able to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

There might need to be an authentication token for 'books' included in the headers.  Check the books.zoho API documentation to see if there is information regarding creating and using an API token.

Also by adding `detailed:true` to the invokeurl call you can get some visibility into any information or error-messages in the response from invokeurl.  Here is some example code:

```
response = invokeurl
[
    url : "https://books.zoho.eu/api/v3/contacts?orgainization_id=20077348839
    type :POST
    parameters:datamap
    connection:"books_contact_auth"
    detailed:true
];

// To see all headers and content
info response;
```

Comment: Thank You for your help!
It didn’t work but it made me think a bit more and ended up making it work!